# check if two inner keys in nested dictionaries are duplicates and retrieve only the highest value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary that looks like this:

```
d = {'DET':{'this':0.5, 'the':0.4}, 'NOUN': {'cat':0.8, 'can':0.2}, 'VERB': {'can':0.6, 'fly':0.3}...}
```

Given a list of tokens I want to check if each of these tokens is in the dictionary and retrieve its value and parent key. If there is ambiguity I can have more than one parent key per token (in my example "can" is a NOUN but also a VERB) and I want to get only the parent key for which my token has the highest value.

So far I have:

```
sent = ['the', 'cat', 'can', 'fly']
for k, v in d.items():
    for token in sent:
        if token in d[k]:
            print token, k, v[token]
```

which gives me for each token all their possible tags and associated values,

```
cat NOUN 0.8
can NOUN 0.2
can VERB 0.6
fly VERB 0.3
the DET 0.4
```

But in the "can" case, I would like to get only

```
can VERB 0.6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would print all tags with the highest value for each token (in case there's both, say, "can VERB 0.6" and "can NOUN 0.6"):

```
from collections import defaultdict

by_token = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(set))

for tag, token_values in d.items():
    for token, value in token_values.items():
        by_token[token][value].add(tag)

for token, by_value in by_token.items():
    value, tags = max(by_value.items())
    for tag in tags:
        print('{} {} {}'.format(token, tag, value))
```

The first loop collects all tags by the same value for each token, using a `defaultdict` which is an easy way to create a nested dictionary structure. For each token, it stores a dictionary mapping values to sets of tags.

The second loop reduces the restructured data to only the max values by using the fact that tuples (dictionary items) are primarily sorted on their first element (the dictionary key, which is the value associated with the tags for the token in question).

Comment: Thank you, I'll go with your answers, it looks like it suits my needs best.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
sent = ['the', 'cat', 'can', 'fly']
found = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    for token in sent:
        if token in v:
            if v[token] > found.get(token, {}).get('val', 0):
                found[token] = {'type': k, 'val': v[token]}
```

And now found looks like:

```
{'can': {'type': 'VERB', 'val': 0.6},
 'cat': {'type': 'NOUN', 'val': 0.8},
 'fly': {'type': 'VERB', 'val': 0.3},
 'the': {'type': 'DET', 'val': 0.4}}
```

Answer (score 0):

So don't print them right away; store them in a dictionary, and when the same case re-appears, only keep the version with the highest value.  When you're done scanning `d`, you can go through this dictionary and print out what is in it.